# Transforming string to datetime in dataframe is slow

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe

I have the following code:

```
from dateutil import parser
df['time'] = df['time'].apply(lambda x: parser.parse(x))
```

I have few hundred thousand rows, and that line takes tens of seconds. Is there any way to optimize it?

Comment: `df.time=pd.to_datetime(df.time)`

Comment: Is it gonna be faster?

Comment: check the answer, I include the time .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `pd.to_datetime`

```
%timeit df['time'].apply(lambda x: parser.parse(x))
1 loop, best of 3: 812 ms per loop
%timeit pd.to_datetime(df.time)
100 loops, best of 3: 4.25 ms per loop


len(df)
Out[290]: 20000
```

Comment: And if it happens to be a datetime already, will this call fail, any way to make it robust to that?

Comment: @BaronYugovich change to `pd.to_datetime(df.time,errors='coerce')`